# Iterate a JMenu on its JMenuItems

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jmenuitem

I am trying to find of way of selecting an element in a JMenu by name.
Basically, what I want to do is this:

```
public boolean setEnableByName(boolean enable, String itemName) {
   for (Component item :  myJMenu.getComponents()) {
      if (item.getName().equals(itemName)) {
          item.setEnabled(enable);
          return true;
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

I have tried iterating on `myJMenu.getComponents()` or `myJMenu.getMenuComponents()`, to no avail. I've searched for the reason and it seems to be caused by the JMenu not stocking directly the submenus and items directly, i.e they're not really present.

There is a similar question on SO, but it dates from 2012, and swing had a lot of changes.

I tested with a JMenu containing 2 JMenus and 2 JMenuItems.
The results I got:

- While using `getComponents()`:
  I never enter the foreach (aka there are no elements returned)
- While using `getMenuComponents()`: I get the two JMenu elements

**NOTE**: Note that I can't use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326806/is-it-possible-to-remove-a-jmenuitem-from-a-jmenu-given-only-the-string-associat) as the elements triggering the action can be anywhere in the code.

**NOTE**: From the tests, I found out that, for my menu, `getComponentsCount` returned 0, `getMenuComponentsCount` returned 4, just like `getItemsCount`.
My problem came from the fact that I was comparing the `name` and not the `text` of my elements.

Comment: Did you add `JMenuItem`s to your `JMenu`? Can you show that code?

Comment: get / putClientProperty help you, is/can be unique, settable, this value (it doesn't make me any sense) can be changed at runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are looking for `JMenuItems` and also that you added them to your `JMenu` using [`add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenu.html#add(javax.swing.JMenuItem)) function. In that case you could use the [`getItemCount()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenu.html#getItemCount()) and [`getItem(int pos)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenu.html#getItem(int)) functions as below:

```
public boolean setEnableByName(boolean enable, String itemName) {
   for (int i = 0 ; i <  myJMenu.getItemCount(); i++) {
      JMenuItem item = myJMenu.getItem(i);
      if (item.getName().equals(itemName)) {
          item.setEnabled(enable);
          return true;
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```